# Equivalent of numpy.put() in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to create an array with a `NaN` everywhere except at certain indices where I place some string.

```
def to_padded_array(vals, idxs, length, fill_na):
    arr = np.array([fill_na] * length)
    np.put(arr, idxs, vals)
    ser = pd.Series(arr)

    return tuple(ser.tolist())
```

I have examples of vals and idxs that look like this:

```
idxs = np.array([0,4,5]) # this was made to be a numpy array
vals = pd.Series(['a', 'b', np.nan], name='city') # this actually would come from a pd.agg function
```

**Note that the initial input `vals` has `NaN`.** If I try to set `fill_na=np.nan`, I get an error saying

`could not convert string to float: 'a'`

If I use `fill_na=None`, I get both `None` and `NaN`, which is **not** good:

```
>>> to_padded_array(vals, idxs, length=6,fill_na=None)
('a', None, None, None, 'b', nan)
```

I was thinking of using pandas to circumvent this issue, but I have yet to find an equivalent for `numpy.put` for pandas. What can I do about this?

Comment: What about reindexing? Something like `pd.Series(vals.values, index=idxs).reindex(np.arange(max(idxs)+1))`

Comment: @ChrisA wonderful, thanks! Worked great, although in my case it's better to use `.reindex(np.arange(length))`. Will be happy to give this an upvote/accept if you can write it down as an answer.

Comment: glad it helped. I've added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) here:

**Example**

```
def to_padded_array(vals, idxs, length):
    # Note that `vals` is a pd.Series object.
    ser = pd.Series(vals.values, index=idxs).reindex(np.arange(length))
    # if vals is an array, then vals can be used instead of vals.values 
    return tuple(ser.tolist())

to_padded_array(vals,idxs, 6)
```

[out]

```
('a', nan, nan, nan, 'b', nan)
```